# Google Earth Font/Icons Oversized

Tags: osx-lion, fonts, google-earth

Google Earth fonts and icons appear oversized.

Here is a screenshot:

[image: Google Earth Large Fonts]

What I've tried so far without success:

- Adjusted font and font size in Google Earth Preferences
- Removed Google Earth including preference files and cache and reinstalled
- Reformatted computer wiping everything clean

Specs Running:

- Mac Mini Server (mid 2011)
- 2 GHz Intel Core i7
- Intel HD Graphics 3000 384 MB
- Mac OS X Server Lion 10.7.5 (11G63)

Thank you for any help you can give!